# How can I block a program's usage for X time?

Tags: windows-10, script, blocking

How can I block a program's usage for X time? I need this because of self control things.

Comment: I never heard about that command, could you explain? thanks!!

Comment: Sorry if I'm being ignorant but, I think that script ends a program and I need to block a program.

Comment: Ohh, I didnt think it that way. Unfortunately, it sounds hard to setup, atleast for me lmao

Comment: I'm really trying my best but it gets so hard when you arent familiar with programming :'(

Comment: Joe - I went ahead and cleaned up my comments and added the detail from the comments to a prettier and a more clear answer for you.

Answer (score 3):

> **How can I block a program's usage for X time?**

You can use [taskkill](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) and [set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) with the `/A` switch to use an arithmetic expression to keep counting up by one and using [ping](https://ss64.com/nt/ping.html) with the `-n 02` pinging the `127.0.0.1` loopback address to ensure each arithmetic operation takes one second.

You then use a conditional [if](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) statement to check that if the number of seconds equals the value of time you tell it to run, it will then end once that is true.

### Batch Script

*I set `numberofsecs=10` so for example you would change that to `numberofsecs=60` for 60 seconds. However long you need this to run preventing the program from running, change that variable value to be the number of seconds for that time period. Be sure to also replace `program.exe` with the name of the program you need to restrict from being executed during this time*

```
@echo on

set numberofsecs=10
set /a count=0

:Loop
ping -n 02 127.0.0.1
taskkill /f /im "program.exe"
set /a count+=1
if not %count%==%numberofsecs% GOTO :Loop
goto :eof
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Taskkill](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)
- [Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [Ping](https://ss64.com/nt/ping.html)
- [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [Counting in a FOR loop using Windows Batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522740/counting-in-a-for-loop-using-windows-batch-script)